# Cannot install SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access due to missing Data Access Object libraries

Tags: windows-10, office365, sql-server, microsoft-access

I have a requirement to migrate some MS Access databases to SQL Server, and would like to use the Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant 8.3 for Access. One of the pre-requisites for installing SSMA is that DAO 12.0 or 14.0 is installed.

After dealing with a rogue 64-bit registration in my otherwise 32-bit Office 365 ProPlus installation, and taking into account that you cannot have C2R and MSI  installations of the same major build version at the same time, I'm now at a point where the SSMA installer just won't recognise that the DAO library is installed.

[image]

I have re-run the installers for both Microsoft Access 2013 Runtime and Microsoft Access 2010 Redistributable, but they both indicate they are already installed.

I don't really want to be running Process Monitor to try and figure out what registry entries the SSMA installer is looking at to determine whether DAO is installed or not...

Perhaps I need to try and install an older version of SSMA?

Comment: You cannot have both a 32-bit and 64-bit Office application installed on the same system.  The error you received indicates your attempting to install a 64-bit Office component while having a 32-bit Office installed.  Uninstall everything, choose 32-bit or 64-bit, then reinstall any Office application you want using the C2R installer

Comment: @Ramhound. No. It is more complicated than that. I've never purposefully installed any 64-bit Office programs. Where that 64-bit registration entry came from is a mystery to me. As you can see from my edits, I've got past that but have not yet got SSMA to recognise any DAO installations.

Comment: I would suggest shrinking the amount of information you have in your question.  If your question is no longer about the C2R errors then you should only include your current problem.

Comment: @Ramhound. I've shrunk the question down to the current problem and summarised the prior difficulties I had to circumvent. Personally, I would have preferred to leave the "work in progress" edits to assist other readers, but that does run the risk of the actual issue getting lost in the noise.